# row-wise Indexing NumPy 2D array by another 2D array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, indexing, scipy

I have a  2-D array like:

```
a = [[0, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 1],
     [2, 2, 2],
     [3, 3, 3]]
```

my index array is like:

```
b = [[0,0,1],
     [2,1,3]]
```

my target array should be like:

```
c = [[[0,0,0],
      [0,0,0],
      [1,1,1]],    
     [[2,2,2],
      [1,1,1],
      [3,3,3]]]
```

how to do it with  NumPy package? is there any built-in function that could do that?
thank you for your help.

Comment: ```a[b]```.--> c ... https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#fancy-indexing-and-index-tricks